# How to add custom controls to an Angular Form

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to build a custom form, where some input fields are used to update lists with bootstrap's typeahead.

add('language', $item) just adds $item to snippet.languages (I'm using one method in my controller to update any list) and resets languagesTh to ''.
Badges just creates an unordered list with a badge for each language and a little cross to splice it from the snippet.languages array.

```
<input class="main-search" type="text" name="subscriber" typeahead-min-length="1" ng-model="languagesTh" typeahead-wait-ms="500" typeahead="languagesTh for languagesTh in getLanguages($viewValue)|filter:$viewValue" typeahead-on-select="add('languages', $item)" placeholder="Add a language">
<badges badge-class="warning" badge-list="snippet.languages"></badges>
<span class="error" ng-show="form.snippet.languages.$error.required">Languages are required</span>
```

My problem is, how do I create a custom controller that automatically sets the form to invalid when the list of languages becomes empty ?

I've tried to add  in the badgelist directive with not empty invalidating the model if the list is empty, but the unshift doesn't even get called when I modify the content...

```
angular.directive('notEmpty', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
          if(viewValue && viewValue.length > 0) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('notEmpty', true);
            return viewValue;
          } else {
            ctrl.$setValidity('notEmpty', false);
            return undefined;
          }
        });
      }
    };
```

What is the best way to create a form control for a specific object ?

**Update**

My current work around is :

```
    $scope.$watch('badgeList', function(newVal, oldVal) {
          if(newVal && oldVal && !(newVal && newVal.length > 0)) {
            $scope.$parent.form.$setValidity($scope.badgeControl+'.required', false);
          } else {
            $scope.$parent.form.$setValidity($scope.badgeControl+'.required', true);
          }
        }, true);
```

However, this forces me to link to the parent (and if I start using custom form names, I'll have to even pass the form name in the scope), which doesn't seem like a very perene solution.

Comment: The unshift shouldn't be called when modifications occur, the link function should only be called when new DOM elements are being create for this directive, the unshift should happen for the number of times it's used.  The function that is unshifted into the parsers should be called every time the value changes though from what I understand.  I don't see where you use your notEmpty directive either?

Comment: I use it in badges, basically it is <ul not-empty></ul>

Comment: All I'm really trying to do, is have the form be invalid whenever a list is empty and display a message when it's both dirty and empty. However these mechanics are only offered parallel to ng-model which only works on primitive types...